# How is it done?

Tags: javascript, error-handling

How does stackoverflow know when the javascript doesn't work, and is able to notify the user on the top of the page?

Is it possible to tell if script doesn't load or produces errors and then still be able to use javascript to generate error message?

Answer (score 2):

## `<noscript>`

Using the `<noscript>` tag:

```
<noscript>
    <div>JavaScript isn't available.<div>
    <div>Please Enable it to continue.<div>
</noscript>
```

### Stack Overflow

Stack Overflow uses this code:

```
<noscript>
    <div id="noscript-warning">Stack Overflow works best with JavaScript enabled<img src="http://pixel.quantserve.com/pixel/p-c1rF4kxgLUzNc.gif" alt="" class="dno"></div>
</noscript>
```

## JavaScript `try..catch`

To handle errors, you can wrap all your JS in a function:

```
try {
    runAllJavaScript();
} catch (e) {
    alert("There was a fatal error :(");
}
```

## Another Example

`eval` *can* be used:

```
var code = new XMLHttpRequest();
code.onload = function () {
    try { eval(code.responseText); }
    catch (e) {
        alert("The JavaScript had an error");
    }
};
code.onerror = function () {
    alert("Script didn't load!");
};
code.open("GET", "path/to/script.js");
code.send();
```

Most people would **not** like this solution as it can be considered "hacky"

Comment: Not quite sure I understand how the JS solution works if JS is disabled.

Comment: @DaveNewton It's not supposed to be if JS failed to load, it's supposed to handle errors

Comment: You covered most of what the OP asked about. But the question also says "Is it possible to tell if script doesn't load?"

Comment: @nnnnnn Pretty simple. Using `onerror`, I've added that

Answer (score 2):

```
<noscript>
    <div id="noscript-warning">Stack Overflow works best with JavaScript enabled<img src="http://pixel.quantserve.com/pixel/p-c1rF4kxgLUzNc.gif" alt="" class="dno"></div>
</noscript>
```

JS loading issues only happen if you can load JS, meaning JS is enabled. The easiest way to determine if JS has loaded is hooking into the load success/failure events, or query on something you know is implemented in the loaded JS (*after* the loading process completes).

Comment: That covers the JavaScript-disabled bit, but what about JavaScript-failed-to-load?